# Can away function like a verb (not a phrasal verb)

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know if **away** can be used as a verb, can I say I away from here? or use this kind of structure, I looked upon different dictionaries but couldn't find any use of away as a verb, does it sound natural to you?
[image]

Comment: Please never ever post pictures of text. These are not accessible or searchable.

Comment: please, could you explain it to me? I don't know what the problem is, I'm just sharing the image from which I  saw the word in context.
is it difficult to view? why do you want to search for it? I only share the picture to give an idea of from I found it. pardon my syntax.

Comment: @OrlandoLazos Some people use things like text-reader software (for instance, if their eyesight isn't good) and a text-reader won't be able to read this image. People might also want to search for your post in the future - maybe somebody else has a similar question, and wants to know if it has already been asked here - and that's much easier if you have posted the text.

Comment: Based on the question and the available answers, it looks like there is a typo in the question. It probably should say “Make someone so frightened that he or she runs away”. As shown, the word away is not used correctly as a verb.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent ah, okay I would bear it in mind. thanks. so do you know if away is used as a verb, does it sound natural to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't standard English usage. As commented by Leatherwing, it's probably a typo and should have been "runs away".

There is [a moderately popular meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally) where writers will deliberately omit the verb as a joke, usually in conjunction with "I accidentally":

> I accidentally a whole pizza
>
> I accidentally 93 MB of files
>
> A large group of people accidentally the US Capitol Building

etc. etc.

In some of these cases, readers are expected to guess the missing verb from context. In other cases, the missing verb is ambiguous and that ambiguity is part of the joke. Either way, it's not 'correct' English grammar and would not be used in formal writing, but you may see it online occasionally.

As noted by tchrist in a comment, old-fashioned English sometimes uses "away" in the same pattern, with the verb "go" left to the reader's imagination, as in this example from Tolkien's "The Hobbit":

> *Far over the misty mountains cold / To dungeons deep and caverns old / **We must away, ere break of day** / To seek our pale enchanted gold.*

You can also hear it in folk music: ["I must away now"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8ELhJ5t8L4). But you wouldn't encounter it in normal 21st-century English. Even back in 1937 when "The Hobbit" was published, I suspect it was deliberately chosen to sound old-fashioned. It's very unlikely that the definition shown in your question was aiming for this old usage.

Comment: *Far over the misty mountains cold / 
To dungeons deep and caverns old /
**We must away,** ere break of day /
To seek our pale enchanted gold.* :)

Comment: @tchrist oh good point! Will add that to my answer.

Comment: It's all because of asking the wrong question. The test left out the verb, probably *runs* as you've said. They just want to see that the student knows what scaring someone off means.

Comment: @tchrist I thought of that usage, but it really seemed that the OP was trying to understand the question that was presented, so I didn’t bring it up. But it is a beautiful use of the word.

Comment: @Leatherwing Yeah, it only **appears** to be a verb in *must away*.  Just as with the imperative  *Away with you now!*, it’s actually an elliptical usage with the verb implied rather than written out. We **did** until not too terribly long ago **use to** use it as a real verb in *to away with something*  meaning to put up with it, but that's now obsolete—at least outside of rural English dialects, for it was last reported in 1890 in Gloucester as being characteristic of that region’s dialectal oddities.

Comment: ' writers will deliberately omit the verb as a joke, usually in conjunction with "I accidentally" '. This appears to be an overgeneralisation of senteces such as "Reread your text carefully to see if you accidentally any words out". The meme is something different, viz a statement which gives advice but contradicts that same advice. If anyone linked the word "accidentally" with leaving a word out, that's a misunderstanding.

Comment: @RosieF I'm aware of that "accidentally any words out" joke, but while it has similarities, it's not quite the same as the meme I mentioned. As you say, that joke depends on the contradiction between advising caution, and including a typo. This meme, OTOH, generally *isn't* structured as advice, and the "accidentally" isn't central to the joke. "Accidentally" is part of the original incarnation of the meme, so it's often used, but I've seen variations that omit it: "I would like to [politician's name here] with a pineapple", that kind of thing.